# Can I send a link from my phone to my desktop?

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android

I have "Chrome To Phone" that lets me click a button on my desktop browser to open the page on my mobile.  I'd like to be able to do the reverse -- sometimes, you take one look at a page and decide that it just isn't suitable for reading on a phone.

I know that I can look at the "tabs on other devices" in Chrome (from the desktop) and see the open page on my phone, but I don't always remember to do so.  I'd like a "push", rather than a "pull".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Push Bullet. 
It let's you push images, links and other things to desktop, tablet, another mobile device etc.

Comment: The features suggest it will solve my problem perfectly.  I'll try it for a while, and (hopefully) report back to let others know my experience.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have WhatsApp or similar an app with group chat feature, you can do the following hack

1. Make a group, call it "test". Add any one contact to this group.
2. Once the group is created, remove this contact from group.
3. Now only you remain in this group. Rename the group as "self notes" and drop yourself any thing you want, text link, images etc.

So you can share any chrome page using WhatsApp to your own group and open your web.whatsapp.com on desktop and access those contents.

Comment: Now that push bullet it's not free anymore it's prefect hack!

Answer (score 0):

There are several services which could be used for that. I'm using [Pocket](http://www.appbrain.com/app/pocket/com.ideashower.readitlater.pro) on my mobiles to mark such articles to "read them later" on my PC – which can be done easily with their browser addon (for me, on Firefox – but they have something for Chrome and Safari as well).

A different approach would be using a shared clipboard: there are several apps available on Android to enable a [Multi-device Clipboard](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_clipboard#group_43).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to download any app or software, you can use [QiikChat](http://qiikchat.com). You will need just to go to the homepage and paste your link. You can see the link again by visiting QiikChat with your other device or mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Scaanin is the easiest solution, just open the website http://www.scaan.in and read how to use. It's the simplest and fastest way to share links from mobile to PC.

You can install the app from [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.watchbird.scaan). Once you install the app, to share links/text, just scan the QR code.

Note: I am the developer of this app. It is new to Play Store, but you can trust that this app is a final product, that has undergone thorough testing.